# static/css/main.dc43fdb9.css from Css Minimizer plugin TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, react-redux

```
pranay@pranay:~/Documents/Code/amazon-clone$ npm run build

> amazon-clone@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.dc43fdb9.css from Css Minimizer plugin
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

the react app runs fine on the development server but shows this error when I try to make it production ready. crosses checked 100 times, nothing seems to work. the static/css/main.dc43fdb9.css isn't part of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottam, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

if you are using any such fancy CSS rules. try disabling them.